# Can I use non-standard English characters in SQL Server tables or columns name?

Tags: sql-server

I am developing system for a language that is not English.

In some cases the table or column names could have some non standard English characters (like ç, ã, é ...).

Can I use those characters in Microsoft SQL Server without any problem?

I know that SQL Server accept those chars. I'm wondering if is this can cause any issue depending on server configuration or anything.

Comment: While SQL Server and also .NET usually work with Unicode characters and therefore have no trouble with non-English, accented etc. characters, we've run into a vast array of other troubles - e.g. when we switched to Git, we experienced trouble since (at the time we started using it) Git was staunchly in the 7-bit-is-enough-for-everyone world. Or we ran into trouble with our build server and tools that just didn't support anything but 7-bit ASCII characters. So in short: yes, *you CAN* - but it's still advisable not to ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  However, the best practice is to conform to the [Rules for Regular Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx):

> The first character must be one of the following:
>
> ◦A letter as defined by the Unicode Standard 3.2. The Unicode
>   definition of letters includes Latin characters from a through z, from
>   A through Z, and also letter characters from other languages.
>
> ◦The underscore (_), at sign (@), or number sign (#).
>
> Certain symbols at the beginning of an identifier have special meaning
>   in SQL Server. A regular identifier that starts with the at sign
>   always denotes a local variable or parameter and cannot be used as the
>   name of any other type of object. An identifier that starts with a
>   number sign denotes a temporary table or procedure. An identifier that
>   starts with double number signs (##) denotes a global temporary
>   object. Although the number sign or double number sign characters can
>   be used to begin the names of other types of objects, we do not
>   recommend this practice.
>
> Some Transact-SQL functions have names that start with double at signs
>   (@@). To avoid confusion with these functions, you should not use
>   names that start with @@.
>
> 2.Subsequent characters can include the following:
>
> ◦Letters as defined in the Unicode Standard 3.2.
>
> ◦Decimal numbers from either Basic Latin or other national scripts.
>
> ◦The at sign, dollar sign ($), number sign, or underscore.
>
> 3.The identifier must not be a Transact-SQL reserved word. SQL Server reserves both the uppercase and lowercase versions of reserved words.
>   When identifiers are used in Transact-SQL statements, the identifiers
>   that do not comply with these rules must be delimited by double
>   quotation marks or brackets. The words that are reserved depend on the
>   database compatibility level. This level can be set by using the ALTER
>   DATABASE statement.
>
> 4.Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.
>
> 5.Supplementary characters are not allowed.

Comment: `When identifiers are used in Transact-SQL statements, the identifiers that do not comply with these rules must be delimited by double quotation marks or brackets` - I have seen people using it verbosely even when this is not the case. Production DDL and DML scripts will be cluttered with square brackets. Most people think this is good practice in all circumstances as SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) also generates all the scripts using `[]` around all SQL objects. SSMS does so just as a precautionary measure but people thought it is a good coding practice or a convention.